# The requested page does not exist

Tags: yii

Не могу понять проблему. Есть страничка для просмотра данных о приложении:

```
mysite/appsinfo
```

чтобы просмотреть приложение нужен его идентификатор, например:

```
mysite/appsinfo/32
```

До добавленных сегодня в базу приложений все шло нормально. Если открыть сегодняшние приложения,то выходит ошибка

```
The requested page does not exist
```

`Url` генерируется все также

```
mysite/appsinfo/183
```

В базе все необходимые данные есть. В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: конфиг роутов скинь

Comment: @Barton это?
> 'routes'=>array(
>    array(
>     'class'=>'CFileLogRoute',
>     'levels'=>'error, warning',
    ),

Comment: для mysite/appsinfo какие настройки роутов?

Comment: @Barton в конфиге настроек для него нету

Comment: @Barton спасибо. не в конфиге дело. Crud не те айдишники ловит=) сейчас поменяю